# Insert statement not working in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I am new to PHP and I am trying to insert a record into a MSSQL table using the script below and an HTML form to enter `Firstname, lastname and age`, but its not working. Any idea?

Script used below:

```
PHP Code
<?php
//mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname); 
 $con=mssql_connect("localhost","sa","10Basana$","my_db");
 // Check connection
 if (mssql_error())
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mssql_error();
   }

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
 VALUES
 ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

if (!mssql_error($con,$sql))
   {
   die('Error: ' . mssql_error($con));
   }
 echo "1 record added";

mssql_close($con);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

to execute the sql query variable. `$sql`

you need to execute

```
mssql_query($sql)
```

else it wont be triggered.

also please dont use the native mssql driver of php as it is not no longer maintaned. Please prefer prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to execute the query with [mssql_query](http://php.net/mssql_query):

```
mssql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now mssql_error() this function not working in php. So try this code.

```
<?php   
$con = mssql_connect("localhost","sa","10Basana$","my_db");
// Check connection

if (!$con) 
{
  die('Not connected : ' . mssql_get_last_message());
} 

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES ('".$_POST[firstname]."','".$_POST[lastname]."','".$_POST[age]."')";

$mydata = mssql_query($sql);

if (!$mydata)
{
  die('MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}

echo "1 record added";

mssql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your help I have tried that and I got this message  MSSQL error: Invalid object name 'Persons'.

Comment: @user2038015 your table name is Persons?

Comment: @user2038015 See my edit answer and try.

Comment: yes tables is Persons.